# How do I add a color overlay on wordpress images/homepage - or an opacity drop? (before-hover)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I add an color overlay or maybe an opacity drop the the images on a wordpress homepage - they have a color overlay on hover - but I want them to be darker in the picture color, as I am trying to go with a dark theme.

As you can see on the left one - I have toned it down a little in photoshop, whereas the right image is how they normally look.

Is there a way to do this rather then possibly toning down every image via photoshop before I upload?

[image: images with text]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the image in a container with the same size and change the opacity of the image, while the wrapper has a dark background color. It might be problematic in IE8.

```css
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
}
img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="img"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I am a complete noob at this stuff haha, is there any way you can guide me on what/where to place this sort of code? Checking the stylesheet of the theme, and its really evading me where this plonks in.

Here is a demo of the actual theme that im using; http://gazette.seoresearch.com/

Comment: The section/module should have it's own code, somewhere. Either in a file or in the WP backend. (My last work with WP is some time ago and I can't work myself into a theme right now.)

Nevertheless, at one point a WP function loads the article's image, just place a `div` around it and give it a class to access and modify your CSS file.